# uitableview scrolling on horizontally

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have `UITableview` problem when scrolling on horizontally.
`UItableview` frame is `(0,0, 500, 200)` and `contetSize` is `(1500, 200)`.

When `contentOffset`  **x** is equal to `frame width`, its content disappears.

Does anybody know how fix it?

Comment: UItableview is {0,0, 500, 200} ??? is this an iPad app ?

Comment: would be better to upload a screenshot of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentOffset.y ? You're setting the contentOffset to 500, which is 300 points "deeper" than your contentSize.y of 200?

Comment: I agree with the poster above who suggests adding a screenshot. It's hard to guess what is actually going on here, but my initial thought is that there is something fundamentally wrong with the layout in general. For instance, why are you using a UITableView (which in its stock form, does not scroll horizontally at all) rather than a UIScrollView? Is the table view inside a scroll view?

Comment: My problem was solved. I was modifying the UIScrollView to work horizontally and this was causing the problem. Now add uitableview inside UIScrollView as suggested. Thank's...